# Javascript bracket notation to access a property/key stored in another variable

Tags: javascript, properties, key

So I'm going through the YDKJS series and I came across this bit that I would like more help understanding [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md):

> Of course, bracket notation is also useful if you want to access a property/key but the name is stored in another variable, such as:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>     a: "hello world",
>     b: 42
> };
>
> var b = "a";
>
> obj[b];         // "hello world"
> obj["b"];       // 42
> ```

I'm having trouble understanding the `var b = "a";` part. Why isn't `b` it's own variable that contains the string `"a"`? It's outside the scope of `obj` but it's referencing the variable in `obj`? And how is it that the `var b` is now a part of obj and you can use `obj[b]` to reference it?

Comment: No, `b` is `"a"`. It has nothing to do with `obj`. `obj[b]` is `obj["a"]` which is `obj.a` which is `"hello world"`. `obj["b"]` is `obj.b` which is `42`. You could as well have chosen `var c = "a"` and `obj[c]` instead.

Comment: OH ok. Got it. Thank you. -duh-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All properties can be access through bracket notation, and the property name as a string. Consider this:

```
'Hello world'.length
```

Is equivalent to:

```
'Hello world'['length']
```

As you can see, the property can be access by brackets and a string representation of the property. So in the example:

```
var obj = {
    a: "hello world",
    b: 42
};

var b = "a";

obj[b];         // "hello world"
obj["b"];       // 42
```

The variable `b` just stores the string 'a', which is then used like this:

```
obj[b] == obj["a"]
```

Above, `obj[b]` is the same as `obj["a"]`.

You have become confused. Variable `b` and `"b"` are not associated. Variable `b` has the value of `"a"`.

The 'a' is just substituted in, which access the a property, returning 'Hello world'. The second access the b property returning 42

Comment: This site has a time limit to how soon you can accept an answer. I will be able to accept in a few minutes :).

Comment: @Burt No problem. If you've got any other questions I'll be glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Xufox has answered my question:

> No, `b` is `"a"`. It has nothing to do with `obj`. `obj[b]` is `obj["a"]` which is `obj.a` which is `"hello world"`. `obj["b"]` is `obj.b` which is `42`. You could as well have chosen `var c = "a"` and `obj[c]` instead.

`obj[b]` is using the variable `b`. Since `b` is `"a"`, `obj[b]` will evaluate to `obj["a"]` which will then evaluate to `"hello world"`.